# speechSynthesisInstance.pause not working on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, text-to-speech

I'm trying the  SpeechSynthesis API, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or if it's a bug, but the pause() doesn't seem to be working...

```js
utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("This is a long text to be read by the voice synthesis. You will see that it doesn't pause when requested to.")
utter.lang = 'en'
window.speechSynthesis.speak(utter)
setTimeout(() => window.speechSynthesis.pause(), 3000)
```

I'm testing with Firefox 80.0.1 (64 bits). Ubuntu 20.04

For me, here, the sentence is read entirely without stopping.

I thought it might be a bug, but I find nothing on the internet about this.

Comment: Works here in FF80.0.1 on macOS.

Comment: I'm with Ubuntu. Maybe this comes from the os then? I'll make extra tests in this direction. Thanks.

Comment: Yes probably, can repro on Firefox for Android.

Comment: Is also not working for me in Firefox 98.0.2 (64 bits) and Ubuntu 20.04 almost 2 years later. I found a report of the problem in the firefox website  that was marked as fixed, but seem to be is not fixed or the problem has happened again.